# How to slice Python Pandas groupby objects with various lengths?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, slice

Creating the dataframe:

`df = pd.DataFrame({'Set': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2], 'Value': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})`

results in the DataFrame as shown below.

[image: Pandas Dataframe]

Next I perform a groupby operation by Set, and the first group is shown below.

```
grouped_by_Set = df.groupby('Set')
grouped_by_Set.get_group(1)
```

[image]

Now I want to select all but the last entry in the Value column per group. I can select the first three (for example) and last entry per group using `grouped_by_Set.nth([0, 1, 2])` and `grouped_by_Set.nth(-1)`, however selecting all but the last entry per group does not work with `grouped_by_Set.nth(0:-1)`. I cannot specify the entries explicitly as the groups have different lengths.

Comment: Kindly post the expected output data frame

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can do with `iloc` in `apply`

```
print(df.groupby('Set').apply(lambda x: x.iloc[:-1]).reset_index(drop=True))
   Set  Value
0    1      1
1    1      2
2    2      1
3    2      2
4    2      3
5    2      4
```

or you could use `duplicated` and keep='last' to create a mask, then use this mask with `loc`

```
print(df.loc[df.duplicated(subset='Set', keep='last')])
   Set  Value
0    1      1
1    1      2
3    2      1
4    2      2
5    2      3
6    2      4
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `tail(1)` to get the last entry of every group and then use the index to deselect it from the original dataframe by inversing `isin`:

```
df[~df.index.isin(df.groupby("Set").tail(1).index)]

# Output:
    Set Value
0   1   1
1   1   2
3   2   1
4   2   2
5   2   3
6   2   4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this using [`reset_index(drop=True)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html?highlight=reset_index#pandas.DataFrame.reset_index) + [`.max()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.max.html?highlight=max#pandas.Series.max) methods, the idea is to use the index for each group in order to set the start and the end of the slice operation:

```
grouped_by_Set = df.groupby('Set')
group = grouped_by_Set.get_group(1).reset_index(drop=True)
start = group.index[0]
end = group.index.max()
df_output = group.iloc[start:end, :]
print(df_output)
```

Output:

**Group 1:**

|  | Set | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |

**Group 2:**

|  | Set | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 4 |